# Another way to calculate cube root in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math

In my calculator I am using these statements to calculate square root and cube root.

```
case "sqrt root":
        result = Math.Sqrt(number1);
break;
case "root":
     result = Math.Pow(number1, (1 / number2));
     //"for cubic root" - Math.pow(number, (1/ 3))
break;
```

I am not very familiar with Math.Pow. Is there another way to calculate cube root? With Math.Sqrt?

Comment: `With Math.Sqrt?` Sqrt means square root, which is different than cubic root

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? `Math.Pow` is the way to do cube roots. I'm not sure why not being familiar with it is a reason to want something else - why not just get familiar with it?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Then the OP should say that. :) My comment was meant to encourage a better question that was more useful to others and more easily answerable.

Comment: @GrantWinney he wouldn't if `number2` is double (in the non-commented code)... but for the specific `1/3`, yes, he would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I somewhere saw how to do cube root with math.sqrt, so I think maybe someone will know here or show me another way, how to do cubic root. –  [user3841611](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3841611/user3841611)

Mathematically, you **can** use Sqrt to get the cube root:

x<sup>1/3</sup> = x<sup>1/4</sup> * x<sup>1/16</sup> * x<sup>1/64</sup> * x<sup>1/256</sup> * x<sup>1/1024</sup> * x<sup>1/4096</sup> * x<sup>1/16384</sup> *...

This comes from the [binary representation](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F3+in+binary&x=0&y=0) of 1/3 and the fact that:

- `Sqrt(x)` is x<sup>1/2</sup>,
- `Sqrt(Sqrt(x))` is x<sup>1/4</sup>,
- `Sqrt(Sqrt(Sqrt(x)))` is x<sup>1/8</sup> etc..
- `Sqrt(Sqrt(Sqrt(Sqrt(x))))` is x<sup>1/16</sup> etc..

In other words, you'd *keep* taking the square root of your number and multiply *every other* value to get x<sup>1/3</sup>. Once the value stops changing (there are limits to floating point precision, so eventually the product won't change), you'll have *something very close to* x<sup>1/3</sup>.

I'll post some pseudo code if you wish.

Comment: Even if this answer has been accepted, I'd argue that if the answer is both mathematically incorrect, and extremely inefficient as a computer algorithm, this goes out of the realm of http://www.stackoverflow.com and if the OP was looking for this solution, the question should have been better off at some other stackexchange site (like http://math.stackexchange.com/ or alike).

Comment: I know and I'm not criticising you at all. I'm criticising the OP's decision to put this as the accepted answer in a site like stackoverflow, and leaving the comment for others that might come into this question (again, in a site like stackoverflow... this would probably be the best solution in some other site)

Comment: (I accidentally deleted this answer then re-added it): FWIW, I agree with you. I posted my answer more as an answer to the point in the original question, "Is there another way to calculate cube root? With Math.Sqrt?". I didn't expect it to be accepted as an answer, nor do I claim that it is in any way efficient. Indeed it is far from efficient. If `Math.Pow` didn't exist, I'd suggest using a non-iterative method like `Math.Log(Math.Log(x) / 3)` 1,000,000 times before I suggested this method.

Answer (score 16):

You'd need to do it with floating point division (doing `1/3` does integer division, which wouldn't work)

```
result = Math.Pow(number, (1.0 / 3.0));
```

But otherwise no, there's no built-in function for cubic root

Comment: Not really. I don't know why but for C# Windows Forms Applications is work this way... without floating point division.

Comment: It works if you use the variable `number2` and that one is `float`, `decimal` or `double`... but if you use the 1/3 constant, it won't. Check it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/U7HpzE

Comment: number2 and number1 and result is all double

Comment: I somewhere saw how to do cube root with math.sqrt, so I think maybe someone will know here or show me another way, how to do cubic root.

Comment: @user3841611 is there any specific reason you wouldn't want to use Pow? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @user3841611 It is impossible to compute a cube root with a square root in general.  This is because cube roots are not constructible in general.  This is related to the problem of [doubling the cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube).

Comment: I've posted an answer for how to get the cube root using only square roots, if you're interested. As @kyle points out, it's mathematically impossible in general, but since we are dealing with finite precision, it is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core has [Math.Cbrt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cbrt?view=netcore-3.0):

```
result = Math.Cbrt(number);
```

This is not available in .NET Framework 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the cube root by multiplying its nesting fourth roots looks okay but assert fails.

```
    static double Sqrt(double x)
    {
        if (x < 0)
            throw new OverflowException("Cannot calculate square root from a negative number");

        double epsilon = 0.0;
        double current = Math.Sqrt(x), previous;
        do
        {
            previous = current;
            if (previous == 0.0)
                return 0;
            current = (previous + x / previous) / 2;
        }
        while (Math.Abs(previous - current) > epsilon);
        return current;
    }

    // Mathematically, you can use Sqrt to get the cube root:
    // x1/3 = x1/4 * x1/16 * x1/64 * x1/256 * x1/1024 * x1/4096 * x1/16384 *...
    static double Cbrt(double value)
    {
        if (value.Equals(1.0))
            return value;

        double nextValue = Sqrt(Sqrt(value));
        return nextValue * Cbrt(nextValue);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string question = "Why does the cube root of {0:0.000} not equal between {1:0.000000000} and {2:0.000000000} ?";
        double value = 2.197, cbrt1 = Cbrt(value), cbrt2 = Math.Pow(value, 1.0 / 3.0), difference = Math.Abs(cbrt1 * .000000001);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(cbrt1 - cbrt2) > difference, string.Format(question, value, cbrt1, cbrt2));
        value = 125.0; cbrt1 = Cbrt(value); cbrt2 = Math.Pow(value, 1.0 / 3.0); difference = Math.Abs(cbrt1 * .000000001);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(cbrt1 - cbrt2) > difference, string.Format(question, value, cbrt1, cbrt2));
        value = 343.0; cbrt1 = Cbrt(value); cbrt2 = Math.Pow(value, 1.0 / 3.0); difference = Math.Abs(cbrt1 * .000000001);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(cbrt1 - cbrt2) > difference, string.Format(question, value, cbrt1, cbrt2));
    }
```